# Error in system header file /usr/include/i386_types.h

Tags: c++, macos

I've been using C/C++ for about 7 months, and am currently trying to write a small set of linear algebra programs. Right now I'm trying to test my vector class, but get the error message:

```
In file included from /usr/include/machine/_types.h:34,
             from /usr/include/sys/_types.h:33,
             from /usr/include/_types.h:27,
             from /usr/include/unistd.h:71,
             from /usr/include/c++/4.2.1/i686-apple-darwin10/x86_64/bits/os_defines.h:61,
             from /usr/include/c++/4.2.1/i686-apple-darwin10/x86_64/bits/c++config.h:41,
             from /usr/include/c++/4.2.1/cstdlib:50,
             from linalgtest.cpp:8:
/usr/include/i386/_types.h:37: error: two or more data types in declaration of ‘__int8_t’
```

In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.2.1/stdexcept:43,
                 from vector.cpp:8:
    /usr/include/c++/4.2.1/exception:40: error: ‘#pragma’ is not allowed here

```
shell returned 1
```

I am running Mac OS X 10.6.5, and have checked my `/usr/include/i386_types.h` file against the one found at http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-1456.1.26/bsd/i386/_types.h. They appear to be the same, for whatever that's worth.

Here are the contents of my tester file

```
#include "linalg.h" // L7
#include <cstdlib> // L8: the offending line
#include <cmath> // L9

using namespace std;

double drand(double d) { return d*((double)rand()/RAND_MAX); }

int main(void) {
   int n = 10;
   double comps[10];
   for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
      comps[i] = drand(10.0);

   vector *v1 = new vector(n);
   vector *v2 = new vector(n, comps);
   v1->print();
   v2->print();

   return 0;
}
```

The offending line (37) from _types.h is:

```
#ifdef __GNUC__
typedef __signed char      __int8_t;  // L37
#else /* !__GNUC__ */
typedef char               __int8_t;
```

From exception (40):

```
#ifndef __EXCEPTION__
#define __EXCEPTION__

#pragma GCC visibility push(default)  // L40

#include <bits/c++config.h>
```

I've done some searching on Google, and seen things involving similar types of errors, but its usually the result of a syntax error in user code. I also see this exact error on the machines in my university's computer lab. They run gcc/g++-4.2.4 on ubuntu lucid. I run gcc/g++-4.2.1 on mac os x 10.6.5.

Answer (score 6):

Usually in C++ you include the system header file(s) you need *first*, followed by your application header files. Try reordering the includes and see if that helps:

### vector.cpp

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>

#include "linalg.h"
```

The exception to this is when you're including the header file that corresponds to the *current* module:

### linalg.cpp

```
#include "linalg.h"

#include <cmath>
// etc

#include "utils.h" // or whatever
```

If you do this, it will ensure that your `linalg.h` header can be included everywhere and it always includes stuff it needs from itself, rather than relying on users to include system things first.

Comment: Wow, that fixed everything. My C/C++ instruction has been kind of informal. Is that also standard operating procedure in C? Thanks a lot

Comment: In general, yes. The preprocessor is one of the areas that is pretty much the same between C and C++.

Comment: Good clue!  Had same compiler message.  Reordering didn't fix the problem for me, but gave a different error message.  That let me home in on the real problem: a class definition lacking a final semicolon!

Comment: Reordering the `#include` directives is a good idea, but it *shouldn't* make any difference.  Something in your `"linalg.h"` header did something that broke `<cstdlib>`.  Does `"linalg.h"` define any identifiers, particularly macro names, that start with an underscore?  All such identifiers are reserved to the implementation, and are not to be defined by user code.