# Migrating code from snow leopard to mountain lion, make and linking errors with 'x86_64'

Tags: macos, linker, x86, osx-lion, x86-64

I have a bunch of code that I frequently use which I bundle as a library (.a).  Everything was working on my old macbookpro running snow leopard; but I've recently gotten a new laptop, and upgraded to mountain lion -- now I'm having lots of trouble building programs that worked before.

At the moment, I'm trying to re-build that library, when I run my makefile, I get the error

```
g++ -g -I/opt/local/include -L/opt/local/lib -M -MT './obj/TB_Numerical.o' TB_Numerical.cpp -MF obj/TB_Numerical.d
make: *** No rule to make target `/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/i686-apple-darwin10/x86_64/bits/c++config.h', needed by `obj/TB_RecordKeeper.o'.  Stop.
```

I'm not versed with makefiles, I just pieced something simple together from a few tutorials etc... If posting my Makefile would help, let me know.

If someone could help me with this particular error, that would be great.
Also, if there's some... like, systematic 'new-thing' I need to be doing to get everything to work right... I'd also appreciate any pointers on that!

Thanks!

Comment: I'm running xcode 4.4 -- but I'm not using xcode for this project, if that makes a difference

Comment: i had this same problem.  installing xcode 4.4 and installing command line tools worked for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5321472/230468

I needed to include system header files **before** application header files...

Why, in the name of anything holy, this error *just* came up after upgrading to mountain lion, an why that particular (seemingly useless) error message was given.... I do not know.