# 'warning: (x86_64) library.a(object.o) object file library.a(object.o) doesn't contain architecture information for x86_64.'

Tags: linker, x86, osx-lion

This may be related to my other issues ([Migrating code from snow leopard to mountain lion, make and linking errors with 'x86_64'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12031786/migrating-code-from-snow-leopard-to-mountain-lion-make-and-linking-errors-with)).  I'm trying to build a program on mountain lion using a library that I made on snow leopard, and I keep getting this error.  I have no idea what it **really** means, nor what to do about it.  Can anyone point me in a (preferably right) direction?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you migrated to a new version of XCode. Did you clean out old .o's and .a's and rebuild them?