# C++ annoying included in file two or more data types

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, header-files

I am attempting to handle the problem that I have not encountered before.

I tried this link, but it did no good to me.
[Error in system header file /usr/include/i386_types.h](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5321455/error-in-system-header-file-usr-include-i386-types-h)
I have attempted to look for possible soultions from similar problems, but it did not help me solve my own problem.

I reordered and did semi colon, but I still get the annoying error

Dealing with the in file included error:

```
g++ -Wall -Wextra -c clock.cpp clock_main.cpp In file included from /usr/include/machine/_types.h:34,
             from /usr/include/sys/_types.h:33,
             from /usr/include/_types.h:27,
             from /usr/include/unistd.h:71,
             from /usr/include/c++/4.2.1/i686-apple-darwin10/x86_64/bits/os_defines.h:61,
             from /usr/include/c++/4.2.1/i686-apple-darwin10/x86_64/bits/c++config.h:41,
             from /usr/include/c++/4.2.1/iostream:44,
             from clock.cpp:2:
/usr/include/i386/_types.h:37: error: two or more data types in declaration of ‘__int8_t’
In file included from /usr/include/machine/_types.h:34,
             from /usr/include/sys/_types.h:33,
             from /usr/include/_types.h:27,
             from /usr/include/unistd.h:71,
             from /usr/include/c++/4.2.1/i686-apple-darwin10/x86_64/bits/os_defines.h:61,
             from /usr/include/c++/4.2.1/i686-apple-darwin10/x86_64/bits/c++config.h:41,
             from /usr/include/c++/4.2.1/iostream:44,
             from clock_main.cpp:2:
/usr/include/i386/_types.h:37: error: two or more data types in declaration of ‘__int8_t’
```

and some files that contribute to the errors

clock_main.cpp

```
#include "clock.h"
#include <iostream> // line 2 cause of error by compiler
using namespace std;


int main(){
  Clock clk_0 (86399); // 1 day - 1 sec
  cout << "initial time" << endl;
  clk_0.print_time();
  ++clk_0;
  cout << "adding one second" << endl;
  clk_0.print_time();
  --clk_0;
  cout << "subtracting one second" << endl;
  clk_0.print_time();


  return 0;
}
```

clock.h

```
#ifndef CLOCK_H
#define CLOCK_H
```

/*
  We make a simple clock class
  and we use the power of overloading operators

*/

```
class Clock{
  public:
    Clock (unsigned int i); // construct and conversion
    void print_time() const; //formatted printout
    void tick(); // add one second
    void tock(); // subtract one second
    Clock operator++() {tick(); return *this;}
    Clock operator--() {tock(); return *this;}
    ~Clock() {}; 
  private:
    unsigned long tot_secs, secs, mins, hours, days;
}

#endif
```

clock.cpp

```
#include "clock.h"
#include <iostream> // the offending line

inline Clock::Clock(unsigned int i){ 
  tot_secs = i;
  secs = tot_secs % 60; 
  mins = (tot_secs / 60) % 60; 
  hours = (tot_secs / 3600) % 24; 
  days = tot_secs / 86400;
};

void Clock::tick(){
  Clock temp = Clock (++tot_secs);
  secs = temp.secs;
  mins = temp.mins;
  hours = temp.hours;
  days = temp.days;
}

void Clock::tock(){
  Clock temp = Clock (--tot_secs);
  secs = temp.secs;
  mins = temp.mins;
  hours = temp.hours;
  days = temp.days;
}

void Clock::print_time() const{
  std::cout << days << " days: " << hours << " hours: " << mins <<
  " minutes: " << secs << " seconds" << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

semicolon

```
class Clock{
  public:
    Clock (unsigned int i); // construct and conversion
    void print_time() const; //formatted printout
    void tick(); // add one second
    void tock(); // subtract one second
    Clock operator++() {tick(); return *this;}
    Clock operator--() {tock(); return *this;}
    ~Clock() {}; 
  private:
    unsigned long tot_secs, secs, mins, hours, days;
}  ;
// ^^
```

Comment: Thank you, I have to remember that declaring an defining classes require a semicolon, or else it will cause an ambiguous header file error. :P